# Showing that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log_{\sin^2x}\cos x}{\log_{\sin^2(x/2)}\cos(x/2)}=4$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log_{\sin^2x}\cos x}{\log_{\sin^2(x/2)}\cos(x/2)}$$
> has the value equal to:
>
> A) $1\quad$ B) $2\quad$ C) $4\quad$ D) none of these
>
> (The answer is $4$.)

As you see in question, it looks like a normal limit question which should be possible using L Hospital, but when I am differentiating, I am always getting $0/0$ and not able to find answer.

Can anyone please explain me how to do it? If we use insane approximations, then you get 4, but the approximations don’t make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This problem becomes significantly easier if you do a bit of manipulation beforehand using the laws of logarithms -- in particular,

- the change-of-base formula $\log_b a = \dfrac{\ln a}{\ln b},$ and then
- the power rule $\log a^b = b \log a.$

After these manipulations, you should reach

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(\cos x) \ln\left( \sin \dfrac{x}{2} \right)}{\ln\left( \cos \dfrac{x}{2} \right) \ln(\sin x)},$$

which you can then factor into a product of two limits (assuming both limits in the product exist, which happens to be the case here).

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln\left( \cos \dfrac{x}{2} \right)} \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln\left( \sin \dfrac{x}{2} \right)}{\ln(\sin x)}$$

To evaluate the limit on the left of the product, apply L'Hôpital's Rule and substitute $x=0$ into the resulting cosine terms, and then do that again. You'll find that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln\left( \cos \dfrac{x}{2} \right)} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{\dfrac{1}{2} \sin \dfrac{x}{2}} = 4.$$

You can evaluate the limit on the right of the product using similar reasoning. It should come out to $1.$